# ClearCase UCM stream with two views on two different hosts

Tags: clearcase, rebase, clearcase-ucm

Has anyone else run into this problem?
Have 1 ClearCase UCM stream. Created a view on my laptop, while on corporate campus.

Am now working remotely, create a  2nd view to same UCM stream on a VM in the corporate data center.

Try to rebase the 2nd view on the vm machine, ClearCase complains that it cannot contact albdServer on my laptop (Atria Location Broker service was not started).

Then it seems that ClearCase proceeds to rebase the first view on my laptop, not the 2nd view from where I asked for the rebase. Rebase is terribly slow, over 1/2 hour for seven files.

I know the first rule of ClearCase, but I am stuck with it ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where the view storage is stored.
The easiest way to debug is to do a:

```
cd /path/to/second/view
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

That way, you can see where the view storage is, and (more importantly), if it is accessible (`dir /path/to/view/storage.vws`)

Comment: Thanks for this, astounding that clearcase will create a view with storage by default on another host. I got around the problem by deleting all the views on the laptop, and the vm. then deleting the view storage directory manually, then recreating views only on the vm.

Comment: @Paulus that is indeed a good solution: that way, you control where the view storage is created

Answer (score 1):

OP: By some wild chance does your domain use roaming user profiles? If you use the view creation wizard, the view creation options are stored in the local user registry so you don't have to reenter them.

If you have roaming user profiles, the local laptop's settings can/will "leak" to the VM. If you used the wizard for the first time on that VM, and didn't get prompted to set a storage location, that's the most likely reason.

Comment: thanks for this, did not even know that this option existed, will check it out when I get a chance.